# How to handle Hibernate session in JTable (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, jtable

I'm using one Session across whole application, but I'm getting error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-9" org.hibernate.AssertionFailure:
>   possible non-threadsafe access to the session

This happens accidentally, not always.

In JTable model I have this:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Invoice i = invoices.get(rowIndex);
        Object[] values = new Object[] { i.getInvoiceId(), i.getIdent(),
                i.getTotalExclVat(), i.getTotalInclVat(), i.getIssueDate(),
                i.getTaxDate(), i.getDueDate(), i.getPayType(),
                i.getWeight(), i.getSupplier().getName(),
                i.getInvoiceItems().size() };
        return values[columnIndex];
...
```

Invoice is Hibernate @Entity and @Table and it has InvoiceItems connected to it.

Question is: How should I handle Hibernate Session in Swing JTables to avoid 'possible non-threadsafe access to the session' error?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide enough code so we can precisely tell you what is the issue.

Comment: Question is if I should share one Session across JTables (getSessionFactory().openSession()) or not. Should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableModel#getValueAt()` is (or should be) running on the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12705700/230513), "each thread/transaction should obtain its own instance from a `SessionFactory`." The factory thread can update the `TableModel` on the EDT via `invokeLater()`.