# JSON mapping problem: possible non-threadsafe access to the session

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am facing a problem due which is unknown to me, can you one have faced this problem?

```
JSON mapping problem: <package>ApiResponse["data"]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: possible non-threadsafe access to the session (through reference chain: <package>.ApiResponse["data"])
```

I have a standard API response pojo. Which I return every time with ResponseEntity. Everything is working fine, but sometimes I got that above error. I don't why this error occurred .

I got the below log from console

```
an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session
```

Comment: This is likely because two threads are using the same session, make sure two threads are not sharing session, you should create new session/transaction if there is another thread involved

Comment: I have a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for the @async job and other one is the main spring boot. is that the problem?

Comment: yes, if the async is using the same session then it will throw error

Comment: do you have any tutorial or link, to separate the session for each? I think the problem is, in @async the tables get an update, and I tried to get the data from same table using API. can this be a problem?

Comment: I debug more and found something Failed to release JPA EntityManager

Comment: I don't think I can help you without more details like getting more details on the environment, possibly how you create multiple threads and use them.  or how you handle sessions etc

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/17379/jpa-entitymanager-hibernate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705700/hibernate-assertionfailure-in-different-threads
are some of the links I can see

Comment: @Nithin I have created a git repo and upload a scenario or scaffolding, how I create in my project, you can check the way. https://github.com/subhendumondal/json-mapping

Comment: I have tried with the answer suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705700/hibernate-assertionfailure-in-different-threads  but nothing worked

Comment: Can you add what are you trying to do from the controller ? Are you trying to perform db operation from controller directly ?

Comment: Yes @AnishB.I try to fetch data from table and rerun as JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to share same Hibernate session within multiple threads. That's illegal.

Hibernate Sessions are not thread-safe whereas Hibernate SessionFactory is thread-safe.

So, make a separate DAO layer. Create single sessionfactory object and share it among the DAO classes.

Get a session for a single-threaded DB operation and close the session in that thread.

For example :

```
@Repository
public class DAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public class performDBOperation(Object obj) {
      Session session = sessionFactory.currentSession();
      session.save(obj);
      session.close(); 
    }

}
```

Now, I have looked at your github code.

I saw the code Exec.java

```
@Service
public interface Exec {

    @Async
    @Transactional
    public void run();
}
```

This is incorrect.

Updated :

```
public interface Exec {

    public void run();
}
```

Update ExecImpl to this :

```
@Service
public class ExecImpl implements Exec {

    @Autowired
    private ExecDAO execDAO;

    @Override
    @Async
    @Transactional
    public void run() {
       // example : create an object to save it.
       Object object = ...; 
       execDAO.saveItem(object);
    }
}
```

Create DAO layer :

Suppose `ExecDAO` interface and implementation `ExecDAOImpl` :

```
 public interface ExecDAO {

        public void saveItem(Object obj);

        // keep here abstract method to perform DB operation 
 }

    @Repository
    public class ExecDAOImpl implements ExecDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public void saveItem(Object obj) {
          Session session = sessionFactory.currentSession();
          session.save(obj);
          session.close(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SubhenduMondal is this answer ok ?

Comment: I am still in trouble, the problem is not solved yet, but I try to follow your suggestion and refactor the project, let see what happen. One Question the interface you write ExecDAO should extend JpaRepository? As All my repository r extending JpaRepository. I am using those to crud operation from controller as well as from async methods.

Comment: @SubhenduMondal  Yeah !! You can take that approach also. But remember while taking the case, please check any issues are there or not while taking that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code at the link you shared in the comment, I think that

```
@Async
@Transactional
```

is a dangerous thing.
I would suggest you to extract a method to do the transactions and try 
what I mean is that,

```
interface ExecImpl{
  @Async
  void run(){
     someThingElse.doTransaction();
  }
}

interface SomeThingElse{
  @Transactional
  void doTransaction();
}
```

I am still not convinced this will help you. But this is something you can try.

I would also suggest to use `readonly` transactions for getting data and not have a single transaction for all purposes.

[This blog](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-transaction) explains why its not good to use these two annotations together whether on a class or on an interface

Comment: can't we have an async method crud enable? why its dangerous thing?

Comment: What if the transaction is created by the proxy before the async annotation is processed, when you do like this you leave a lot to chance and that too on the interface. 
Spring does not recommend these annotations on the interface because the class-based proxying infrastructure and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy  if you use class based proxies

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

you can check this page to see the consequences of annotation on interface